# How to assign value to each character in string Java

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I take in a `txt` using Processing software and assign it into a array so for instance a something like this:

```
dog
cat
wolf...
```

But then I need to have `a = 1`, `b=2`, `c=3`, etc... to have values so in the end the full words will add up and that way I can find which word has the largest value.

I could do a ton of `if` statements but 26 of them would be too many and unnecessary. So in that case what would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Characters already have an integer value. You can just cast a `char` to an `int` and get its ASCII value: http://www.asciitable.com

Comment: BTW not only are `char` actually stored as integers, but `float`, and `double` and `boolean` and even references can be accessed as integers. This is because all data is accessible as multiple 8 bit bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char` is already a numeric value. It's just the representation on the screen and the data-type that differs from other integral types. To be more precise, Java's `char` supports UTF-16 and is thus 16 bits long, just like a `short`-value. So there's no need to reassign any values to characters. In fact that approach would be rather error-prone (missing characters for e.g.) compared to the already existing charsets.

If you only want to store characters of the alphabet as numbers, like "a=1", "b=2", etc., just use `int v = inputChar - 'a' + 1` for lower-case letters and apply the same principle to upper-case letters with 'A' instead of 'a'.

Comment: If you use modulus you can map 'A' and 'a' at the same time.

Comment: So far instance I do a for loop that goes through the characters in word and once found input the letter/char into "inputChar". Then take take v and add it to the array that stores the words value?

Comment: @TechAssassin could you illustrate with some code in the question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know. I just used the more simple solution since OP apparently isn't that adept to character-representation.

Comment: @TechAssassin exactly. The example with `v` shows how to convert a character to `int` with a=1, b=2, etc., just loop over the characters of the string, convert each of them and sum the values up.

Comment: Wow Thank you this helped a lot! I got it finished. Thanks for posting this @Paul

Answer (score 1):

[The Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/) should be your first stop for questions like these. The [loadStrings()](https://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html) reference shows you exactly how to read a file into an array and then iterate over the Strings using a for loop:

```
String lines[] = loadStrings("list.txt");
println("there are " + lines.length + " lines");
for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.length; i++) {
  println(lines[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> have a = 1, b=2, c=3, etc... I could do a ton of If statements but 26 of them

Or you could do

```
char ch = ...
int a = ch & 0x1f;
```

or

```
int a = ch % 32;
```

or

```
int a = ch - 'a' + 1;
```

In each case this uses basic maths.  The ASCII values for 'a' to 'z' are  in this table.

http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

As you can see, 'a' starts at 97 which is in the 3rd and last block of 32 characters in the ASCII table so when you either modulus by 32 or use & 31 you have mapped `A` and `a` to 1 and `B` and `b` to 2.  If you want to check for characters outside this range I suggest you valid the character first with an if statement.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but an explanation of what's going on there would be helpful.

Comment: @Zar good point.  I forget most developers don't know their ASCII tables these days ;)